# Closest minyan to Boston Logan Airport?

Tags: minyan

I am looking for a minyan closest to Boston Logan airport on a Sunday morning?
Thanks to all

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Isac and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 1):

Try using https://www.godaven.com/search?mode=location&address=Boston%20Logan%20International%20Airport%20(BOS),%20East%20Boston,%20MA%2002128,%20USA&lat=42.36557519999999&lng=-71.0097645 .

Nearest is

> the zvhil - mezbuz beis medrash (downtown boston) 15 School St,
> Boston, MA 02201, USA [www.Rebbe.org](http://www.Rebbe.org) (617) 227-8200 info@rebbe.org last
> updated: July 24, 2022